# Why can't I call a setter via the string defined in an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's consider the following:

```
export default () => {
  let _message = '';

  return  {

    set message(msg) {
       _message = msg;
    },

    get message() {
      return _message;
    }
  }
}
```

Let's assume you import this as `Message`.

`const message = Message();`

Now let's give you an object: `const messageObject = {setterName: 'message'};`

So let's do this:

```
const setterName = messageObject.setterName;
message.setterName = 'hello world';

console.log(message.message); // => ''
```

**Why is this empty? Why can I not do this? Is there something I missing?**

*How would I make this work, if possible?*

### Update

Some of you seem to be deeply confused. Lets consider how you would actually use the above code as opposed to how I am using it:

```
const message = Message();
message.message = 'hello world';
console.log(message.message); // => 'hello world';
```

The object:

```
const messageObject = {setterName: 'message'};
```

contains a `setterName` key, with a vale of `'message'`. In this case I should be able to do the exact same thing as I did above, accept I should be able to use `setterName`:

```
const setterName = messageObject.setterName; // This is message. Remember that.
message.setterName = 'hello world';

// The above (should) in my mind should be the same as:
// message.message = 'hello world';

console.log(message.message); // (should) => 'hello world'
```

I hope this makes things more clear. In other languages like PHP I would do:

```
call_user_func_array(array(Message, 'setMessage'), array('hello world'));
```

Notice how `setMessage` is in quotes. Well I am trying to do the same thing here.

Comment: Did you try not using `const` for everything ?

Comment: Const. as I understand it is readable only variable and so I should be able to set said function to a const and then call said functions  setter I should be able to set it ... Unless you have a detailed explanation AND answer

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting, what is `setterName` for?

Comment: If you say so, this is way too complicated for me, I don't see any relevance from `messageObject` to the actual import, or anything calling the setters and getters ?

Comment: @elclanrs your answer makes no sense please provide an actual answer I can vote on

Comment: @KyleAdams It's not an answer, it's a clarifying comment. Please describe what you expected to occur, or what you hoped to achieve.

Comment: I think we're both asking the same thing. You have `const setterName = messageObject.setterName;`, but why, what does that do? It's not related to anything at all, and `message.setterName` is not related to .. anything, and why would any of that change `message.message`

Comment: I think OP is misunderstanding how getter/setter works. It is not a catch-all method if that's what you are expecting. `message.message = 'baz'` will run the setter. `message.message` will run the getter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this:

```
var o1 = { prop:"cats" };
var o2 = { cats:42 };
var propertyName = o1.prop;
console.log( o2.propertyName  ); // undefined
console.log( o2[propertyName] ); // 42
```

You set `setterName` to the string `"message"` (via a convoluted route, as I did above), but then you try to talk to `message.setterName`—the property NAMED "setterName"—instead of `message[setterName]` which is the same as `message.message`.

If you change your code to:

```
message[setterName] = 'hello world';
```

…then it will do what (I think) you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the answer, I guess we all missed the question. It is a dot notation vs bracket notation misunderstanding.

Comment: I hope. It's a stab in the dark. Kyle, please remember, for future questions, that it's as important to say what you _expected_ to happen when you show what is going wrong. (Ah nice, you just edited your question with clarifying details. Well done.)